# Cloud Function returns undefiend when using POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, post, fetch-api

I am trying to send the param `name` in the Cloud Function managed by Firebase using POST method, I've read quite a few documentation, and no matter what I try it always returns undefined. Also is it safe to use this for sensitive data?

**Client-Side**

```
fetch(`https://<<APP-NAME>>.cloudfunctions.net/addCardForExistingCustomer`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      JSON.stringify(body: {'name': 'Name'})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**Server-side (Firebase Cloud-Functions)**

```
exports.addCardForExistingCustomer = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

  let name = await request.body.name
    
  response.json({
    response: `${name}`
  })

})
```

Comment: With fetch you need to send JSON body **as** JSON, not as an Object ... `JSON.stringify(body: {'name': 'Name'})`

Comment: *is it safe to use this for sensitive data* - as safe as any HTTPS is

Comment: How would you write it in the fetch function correctly?

Comment: I told you in the first comment ... you send JSON, then I even showed the code

Comment: I edited the code above, did I put it correctly, I think that is a syntax error, I'm fairly new to programming

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo :p it's `body: JSON.stringify({'name': 'Name'})` - my bad

Comment: Sorry about my typo :p